# Aligning an equation at multiple places

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I want to align an equation at two places, and I have a code segment that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
g_P^x &= 3x_P^2 + a, \quad g_P^y &&= -2y_P, \\
v_P &= 2g_P^x, \quad u_P &&= (g_P^y)^2, \\
v &= \sum_{P \in G^+} v_P, \quad w &&= \sum_{P \in G^+} u_P + x_Pv_P.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

And this works to a certain extend, but there is a big gap between `u_P` and the equal sign. How can I get it closer to the equal sign so it is aligned with the stuff above and below it?

Comment: Why `&&`? Try putting the extra `&` before `g_P`, `u_P`, and `w`.

Comment: Because I thought, the first alignment point should be specified with `&` and the second one with `&&`. Can you write as answer, what you mean?

Comment: No, each `&` is an alignment point, just like in tables. Put an `&` before `g_P`, `u_P`, and `w` to align them too.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: I don't interpret `&`s like that: the first one introduces a new column of alignment,, and the second one marks  the alignment point inside this column.

Comment: @Bernard Hmmm... I didn't know that. Looking at your answer, it makes total sense. +1 :)

Comment: This is due to the repeating scheme for alignments: `r&l & [r&l] & [r&l] …`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must understand that in an align(at) environment with multiple alignment points, each even order `&` introduces a new column of alignment, and each odd order `&` marks the alignment point inside its column . That's why *n* alignment points require *2n-1* `&`s.

Applying this rule, and using the `\smashoperator` command  from `mathtools` to improve the layout of big operators with wide sub/superscripts, you get this code (note you need only one `\qquad` in a well-chosen row):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
g_P^x &= 3x_P^2 + a, &\qquad g_P^y&= -2y_P, \\
v_P &= 2g_P^x, & u_P &= (g_P^y)^2, \\
v &= \smashoperator{\sum_{P \in G^+}} v_P, & w&= \smashoperator{\sum_{P \in G^+}} u_P + x_Pv_P.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]